# How do you keep the value of a global variable when using that global variable as the name of a file?

Tags: python, global-variables, variable-assignment

I am looking to find out how to make a global variable assigned to a value in a different function to keep the value when used to append a file. P.S. This is a simplified version of my code there isn't a way for them to be in the same function.

```
def data():
    with open (username+'.txt','a') as f:
           f.write("\n")
def login ():
     username=input("What is your username. ")
     global username
login()
data()
```

It comes up that username isn't defined although it says that I am not allowed to do:

```
 with open (global username +'.txt','a') as f:
             f.write("\n")
```

so I don't know how to keep the value.

Comment: Even simplified versions of your code should be runnable. Please reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates your error. Your code has multiple syntax errors. Even when those are fixed, your code never runs because no one ever calls `data()`. When *that* problem is fixed, your code [runs perfectly with the intended result](https://ideone.com/VUvXYH). Please [edit] your post and copy-paste (never retype) that program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: When you run the code as it currently appears in your question, what error message do you get? Please copy-paste the entire error message text into your question, including any traceback.

Comment: Thank you for your help just realised I indented something in my code that affected it.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare first the variable in the global scope, and should use 'global variable' before using the value and not after.

here is a working sample to you.

```
username = None

def data():
    global username
    username  = 'teste1'



def login():
    global username
    print('username before login : ', username)
    username = 'changed'
    print('username after login : ', username)


data()
login()
```